# ¿Cómo paso el valor de una variable o un objeto entero de una clase a otra?

Tags: java

Tengo un DAO B en el que tengo el siguiente método:

```
 public static ArrayList<Cita> getAllCitas(Connection conn, Long idPaciente)
    throws SQLException {
        return factory.getAllCitas(conn, idPaciente);
    }
```

Y un DAO A en el que tengo acceso a conn e idPaciente. Aquí necesito averiguar el iDCita del objeto Cita.
Intento hacer lo siguiente:

```
ArrayList <Cita> citas = bDAO.getAllCitas(conn, user.getIdPaciente());
        for (Cita c: citas) {
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()){ log.debug("La idcita sera -> " + c.getIdCita());}
        }
```

Pero la idcita siempre me aparece como null.
¿Dónde está el error, como puedo enviar el objeto con sus datos de un DAO a otro? ¿O en su caso sólo la idcita?

Comment: No logro entender el problema. Quizá estés enfocando mal la forma de informar los objetos. ¿`Cita` no es una propiedad del objeto `Paciente`?

Comment: Primero, nomenclatura, no pasas objetos entre *clases*, lo pasas entre *instancias* (u objetos). Las clases son estáticas, son las instancias/objetos lo que creas durante el programa. Y en tu código estás pasando el arraylist y las citas correctamenete, si c.getIdCita() es null es porque el problema está al obtener los datos de la base de datos o similar, no al pasar de DAO B a DAO A

Comment: Es decir, después de llamar a *factory.getAllCitas* lo que obtienes ya tiene el problema de que *getIdCita* devuelve null, no "pierdes" esa información al pasar de DAO B a DAO A.

Comment: @A.Cedano no, es `Paciente` propiedad de `Cita`

Comment: Ok, entiendo. Como ha comentado @SJuan76, revisa en `DAO B` que los datos están llegando bien, pues parece que el problema está ahí.

Comment: Debo enfocarlo así, ¿Probar que en `DAO B` se está recibiendo el dato?